# How do I ignore the "File Not Found" string in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, string-comparison

I'm writing a batch file that will work with sub folders in a `Repository` folder.

**Example:**

```
Repository\Landscape
Repository\Batman
```

Any  file under the `Repository` folder that **isn't** a folder, is ignored. To work with the subfolder, I use a `for /f` loop with the `dir` command, but if the folder is empty, it returns `File Not Found`. Is there a way I can filter that output out? I tried [string comparison](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html), but it doesn't seem to work.

**Code**:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set repository=%userprofile%\Repository

if exist "%repository%" (
    cd "%repository%"
    for /f %%G in ('dir /l /b /a:d %repository%') DO (
        rem We know we're only working with folders.
        set subfolder=%%G
        echo !subfolder!
        for /f %%n in ('dir /b /a:-d !subfolder!') DO (
            set "filename=%%n"
            set "ignorestring=File Not Found"
            if /I NOT !filename!==!ignorestring! (
                echo %%n
            )
        )
    ) 
)
```

Comment: You should really have used, `set "repository=%userprofile%\Repository"` and `if exist "%repository%\" (`, however, I'd suggest that you delete `if exist "%repository%" (` and change `cd "%repository%"` to `CD /D "%repository%" 2>NUL && (` instead.

Comment: As for your issue, you only need to redirect the error message to the NUL device, so change, `dir /b /a:-d !subfolder!` to `dir /b/a-d "!subfolder!" 2^>NUL` instead. You will then not need to check for the error string as it will not pass to the `Do` portion of your loop.

Comment: @Compo - Why delete the `if` statement? I thought it was good practice to check if the directory exists first before working with it.

Comment: nsutilities, we do not need to check if it exists because `CD /D "%repository%"` changes to that directory. If the change happens, the directory must exist, and any code within the parentheses beginning here, `&& (`, will be run. If the directory change doesn't happen, it doesn't exist, the error message will be sent to the NUL device, `2>NUL`, and none of the code within the parentheses beginning here, `&& (` will be run.